# Spring boot RequestMapping on root, how to exclude a directory for static file serving?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My spring-boot web service with spring-mvc has a quite generic endpoint defined by

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

For legacy/compatibility reasons it is hard to change that.

My problem is that this overwrites the out-of-the-box static file serving, namely my auto-generated swagger.json which I have under target/classes/static/swagger.

Is there any way to exclude my "swagger" directory from that RequestMapping?

Comment: Why not add a more specific mapping like `@RequestMapping(value = "/swagger", method = RequestMethod.GET)` ?

Comment: Thx! I hoped for a solution that just allows me to return to the spring default for this path. But yes I guess this is what I'll do.